# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50c05) with this library (version 0x50c06)

Tags: windows, qt, upgrade, mismatch

I just installed Qt 5.12.6 and removed Qt 5.12.5. This is on Windows, QT 5.12.6 is the only Qt version installed in a system. There are copies of Qt 5.12.5 in some folders but I'm 100% sure they are not on a path or anything. I first removed 5.12.5, then installed 5.12.6. I thoroughly cleaned the project - removed all files generated during build as well as deleting *.pro.user file (Warning! This will remove your project's build settings. I knew it will happen and was prepared to set everything from scratch). Then I rebooted my computer - nothing worked.

Now my software again and I will post the last thing I tried as an answer to this question so that others in a future can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local" folder Qt created subfolders \cache\qmlcache. After deleting the  folder my app started working again.